# Trigger to automatically calculate area when adding polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgis

I need help with writing a trigger to automatically update and insert into a column the area of a polygon being created using PostgreSQL/PostGIS and QGIS.

This is what I have but it's not updating when I add new features.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc_area()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
NEW.area_ha := ROUND((st_area(NEW.geom::geography)/10000)::numeric,2);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER area_calculate AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON public."Guyana_Coastal_Zone"
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc_area();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not a very good idea, and there is no need to do this. Just create a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html).

```
CREATE INDEX ON table ( ROUND( (ST_Area(geom)/1000)::numeric ,2 ) );
```

I would create the index on the unrounded version.

```
CREATE INDEX ON table ( ST_Area(geom) );
```

Then a query like this:

```
SELECT * ON table WHERE ST_Area(geom) > x;
```

will use the index. Alternatively, you can create a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html). Generally, it's not a good idea to cache the result of a calculation on the table.

Shy of that, **if you really want to store the computed column on the row your trigger needs to be `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE`.** I really wish returning non-null in `AFTER` would generate a warning, but it's [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) (emphasis added):

> The return value of a **row-level trigger fired AFTER** or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER **is always ignored; it might as well be null.** However, any of these types of triggers might still abort the entire operation by raising an error.